# My Downloadable Products Menu Missing

Tags: magento-1, downloadable, custom-menu

Earlier I was not selling any digital downloadable products so I had removed `My Downloadable Products` option from customer account menu by replacing :

```
<?php $count = count($links); ?>
```

with

```
<?php $_count = count($_links);
 unset($_links['downloadable_products']);
?>
```

but now I have started selling downloadable products so I want the option back.

I replaced the above unset code with `<?php $count = count($links); ?>` but still the downloadable option is not showing up.

I checked `downloadable.xml` and could find

```
<customer_account>
    <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="downloadable">
            <name>downloadable_products</name>
            <path>downloadable/customer/products</path>
            <label>My Downloadable Products</label>
        </action>
    </reference>
</customer_account>
```

I have tried copying base files like `downloadable.xml`, `checkout.xml`, `downloadable (Directory)`, `customer (Directory)`, etc. to the customized theme. I also tried by deleting or renaming those files from custom theme. It didn't help at all. Is the menu disabled in the database? How can I get it back?

Comment: Did you check under System > Configuration > Advanced if the module output for Mage_Downloadable was set to Yes ? If it is set it back to No. Also ensure that under `app/etc/modules/Mage_Downloadable.xml` active is set to true

Comment: You are right. I should have switched `Configuration Scope` to the right store and checked the module under Advanced option. This very small mistake took 4 hour to figure it out.  You solved it.

Comment: I posted it as an answer, feel free to mark your question as answered ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reckon you should check under **System > Configuration > Advanced** and ensure that the **Mage_Downloadable** module output is not set to disabled.

Also ensure that under `app/etc/modules/Mage_Downloadable.xml` active is set to true.